# Show $C(B) = C(1) + (1-B)C^*(B)$ where $C(B), C^*(B)$ is are $\infty$-order polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials, power-series, time-series

Let $C(B)$ be a $\infty$-order polynomial: $$ C(B) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k B^k$$

Show that $$C(B) = C(1) + (1-B)C^*(B)$$ where $C^*(B)$ is a another $\infty$-order polynomial.

This comes from the prove of the Engle-Granger Representation Theorem in their [original paper](http://www.uta.edu/faculty/crowder/papers/Engle_Granger_1987.pdf)

Here, the polynomials $C(B), C^*(B)$ are moving-average polynomials in time series analysis.

I can't seem to understand how its derived... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $1$ is in the convergent domain of $C$.
\begin{align}
C(B)-C(1) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k B^k-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k 
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k (B^k-1)
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k (B-1)\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}B^n
\\
&=(B-1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\alpha_k B^n
\\
&=(B-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \alpha_k
\\
&= (1-B)C^*(B)
\end{align}
where
$$
C^*(B)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \alpha_k
$$
$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \alpha_k$ exists because $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k$ converges.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how you went from lines two to lines three. Any hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, you need to show every coefficient on the left is equal to the analogous coefficient on the right.  To do so, you can use induction, so start with $k=0$, which is trivial, and proceed as you would in the iteration if an induction proof.